# PHP Docblock #@+ meaning

Tags: php, comments, docblocks

What is the meaning of the following in a php docblock:

```
#@+
```

An example in the zend framework code:

```
/**#@+
 * @const string Version constant numbers
 */
const VERSION_10 = '1.0';
const VERSION_11 = '1.1';
/**#@-*/
```

Im assuming its used to group related items but cant see for certain.

Also, its syntax is very odd - how does it translate when documentation is generated from it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a docblock [template](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#basics.docblocktemplate), so every documentable element (every const in this example) between the template has the same documentation.